# Exporting FFT script data into a text file

Tags: python, scipy, export, text-files, fft

I have question about the script our teacher gave us in the student's laboratory course. The script is written in Python 2 and imports data from a mic.txt file, performs a FFT transform and then plots the data. What I would like to have is that the script would also make a txt file containing 2 columns with the plotted data numbers so that I can then use the results for further analysis.

I would appreciate your help, Matthew

```
from scipy.fftpack import fft,ifft
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import blackman

data =  np.loadtxt("mic.txt")
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]

fy = fft(y)
ft = np.fft.fft(y)

print np.sum(y),"==",fy[0]

n = len(x)
t = x[-1]
fx = np.linspace(0,n/t,n)

plt.plot(fx[0:n/2],np.abs(fy[0:n/2]))

plt.xlabel("frequency (Hz)")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Google is your friend bt as you're new have a look [here](https://www.guru99.com/reading-and-writing-files-in-python.html). In the future you should know these types of questions dont go down well on here.

Answer (score 1):

Provided the two columns are of equal length, you can write them to a text file as follows:

```
with open('text_file.txt','w') as f:
    for a,b in zip(variable_1, variable_2):
        f.write(str(a) + ',' + str(b) + '\n')
f.close()
```

Comment: Hi @washersl if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.